# Updating UI with messages from thread

Tags: .net, wpf

I think this might have been asked before, but I'm probably too stupid to understand the answers that were given so I need to ask again.

I have a class which performs calculations on some data. During calculation I would like to output error notifications from data checks, status updates and the data line to the UI. I would like to do this in real time. The problem I am having when calling this from within the main application is that the UI (in WPF) freezes until all calculations are complete and then all messages are displayed in one go. That is problematic for calculations which take 20 to 30 seconds to finish.

So I am trying to use threading. This is pretty much my first attempt at this stuff. I am doing something like:

```
private void btnStartCalculations_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        //initialise parameters for run
        calculator = new Calculator(...);
        //Subscribe to calculator events for update
        kasenCalculator.OnStatusUpdate += new Calculator.UpdateEventHandler(calculator_OnStatusUpdate);
        //kasenCalculator.OnErrorLogUpdate += new Calculator.ErrorLogUpdateEventhandler(calculator_OnErrorLogUpdate);
        //kasenCalculator.OnDataReadUpdate += new Calculator.DataReadUpdateEventHandler(calculator_OnDataReadUpdate);

        //Run
        Thread thread = new Thread(calculator.Run);
        thread.Start();
}

private void calculator_OnStatusUpdate(object sender, string Message)
{
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action<string>(UpdateStatusWindow), Message);
}

private void calculator_OnDataReadUpdate(object sender, string Message)
{
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action<string>(UpdateOriginalDataWindow), Message);
}

private void calculator_OnErrorLogUpdate(object sender, string Message)
{
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action<string>(UpdateErrorLog), Message);
}

private void UpdateStatusWindow(string Message)
{
        TextBox statusWindow = this.txtStatus;

        //Add status text
        statusWindow.Text += Message + "\r\n";
        //Scroll to bottom of window
        statusWindow.CaretIndex = statusWindow.Text.Length;
        statusWindow.ScrollToEnd();
}

private void UpdateOriginalDataWindow(string Message)
{
        this.txtOriginalData.Text += Message;
}

private void UpdateErrorLog(string Message)
{
        this.txtErrors.Text += Message + "\r\n";
}
```

Which sort of works in that the UI **is** getting updated, but it is still not very responsive. I was wondering if I should use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`, but that just keeps all the updates back until the calculations have finished running and I might as well have execute in the main thread.

Also, even though this is running, it is actually running a lot slower than I expected.

Is this the right way to go about doing what I am trying to do?　If not, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for an async call to the UI thread.  Your use of `Invoke` is blocking.

---

Your performance issue may be related to string concatenation.  Do you have a lot of log messages?

Perhaps use an `ItemsControl` and bind an `ObservableCollection<string>` to it.  Then just add your log messages to that collection

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using the ItemsControl, that's much better than appending to text boxes. As for the BeginInvoke... When I replace Invoke with that, my UI doesn't refresh anymore and I don't understand why... Is it waiting on something? Is there a way to force processing of all pending tasks?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any further insight for you on this one.  I can't imagine why it wouldn't update given that change.

Comment: Hope you don't mind this (very late) but I'm curious what you ended up doing? Also, `calculator_OnStatusUpdate` executes on the worker thread so seems to me that `Dispatcher` belongs to that thread not the UI thread. (Note: I haven't used WPF.) One way to specify the correct one is: `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`.

Comment: I worked out that `Dispatcher` is a property on the WPF `Window` class. Sorry, I see there's no ambiguity after all.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it correctly. If it's important make the Dispatcher priority higher...

```
UpdateLayout();
```

This will force your UI to reload. Make sure this is done on the main UI thread. The use of

```
BeginInvoke();
```

is asynchronous and I experienced times where it took about 30 seconds to finish.